# Does an iOS subscription renewal convey the applicationUsername?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

It’s troublesome matching iOS in-app purchase renewals with their original buyer. You *could* use the [`original_transaction_id`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) if it was reliable, but it is not. It [does not change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19000758/2083613) with new subscriptions, which might be made by another user using the same Apple ID.

For this reason, the [documentation suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW6) to “populate the `applicationUsername` property” as an opaque identifier uniquely identifying the buyer. It is definitely provided with the initial receipt.

If an auto renewing subscriptions renews, the [`TransactionObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/) receives a new receipt and a `transactionIdentifier` for the renewal, right?

**Does a renewal also comprise the `applicationUsername`?**

Comment: FYI: In June 2015, we also submitted a bug report to Apple. It has never been replied to.